# How is transaction id wraparound prevented on write-only tables?

Tags: postgresql

We have a table where we store events. This is an append-only table with 4 billion rows/events in it. We never delete nor update the rows in this table, hence we never have `dead_rows` in it.

AFAIK [transaction id wraparound](https://kb.timescale.cloud/en/articles/2755209-postgresql-transaction-id-wraparound) is prevented by frequent runs of [AUTOVACUUM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-autovacuum.html).

However to my understanding, AUTOVACUUM never runs on write-only tables because they don't have dead rows in them hence they never exceed the `autovacuum_threshold`.

How would transaction id wraparound be prevented in such a case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age`, which defaults to 200 millions.

Once a table has an unfrozen live row that is more than `autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age` transactions old, autovacuum will launch an worker that performs an anti-wraparound vacuum on the table and freezes rows older than `vacuum_freeze_min_age` transactions.

Note that from PostgreSQL v13 on, autovacuum is not only triggered by dead tuples, but also by the number of rows inserted (based on `autovacuum_vacuum_insert_threshold` and `autovacuum_vacuum_insert_scale_factor`). That allows freezing rows earlier, and reduces the impact of an anti-wraparound vacuum. See [my blog post](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-autovacuum-insert-only-tables/) for details.